# Androidアプリ で logcat:「Future Android versions will throw an exception.」等のエラーログの影響について知りたい

Tags: android, exception

現在Androidアプリケーション(自社開発/GooglePlayストア非公開)の動作検証を実施しており、以下のようなエラーログがlogcat上に出力されている状況です。
※Android 10向けに作成したアプリケーションがAndroid 13で動作させた場合に
どのような影響があるか検証しております。

■検証条件
OS: Android 13
targetAPI: 30

■ログ1

```
E/ViewRootImpl(20470): Accessibility content change on non-UI thread. Future Android versions will throw an exception.
E/ViewRootImpl(20470): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

■ログ2

```
(19799): Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libmagtsync.so" not found
```

上記エラーログはlogcat上に出力されておりますが、特にアプリケーションはクラッシュすることなく正常な動作をしております。
try-catch内の処理で発生しておりますが、どちらもException内の処理にも入りません。

ログ1について、UIスレッド以外でのViewの更新が原因?のようですが、「Future Android versions will throw an exception.」は将来的にExceptionを吐く可能性があるが、今は問題なく動作しているという理解で良いでしょうか。
※Android 10では本エラーは出力されませんでした。

ログ2について、libmagtsync.soはどのような役割を持つライブラリでしょうか。

また上記2つのエラーについて、アプリケーションにどのような影響が考えられるでしょうか。
※対象のアプリケーションに対して全機能を検証しましたが、いまのところ影響がある箇所は見つかっておりません。

ご教示いただければ幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。